# Running jar created under windows under linux

Tags: java, linux, jar, executable-jar, raspbian

I have created an JavaFx project under windows with netbeans. If a take the created jar file from the "dist" folder and run it with doubleclick it works fine under windows. But if I take the same jar und run it under linux(raspian) i get this error: `Error: Could not find or load main class ...`

I run the jar with the command:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

On windows i have the java version: `1.8.65`
Under raspian i have:

```
java version "1.8.0_73"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_73-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.73-b02, mixed mode)
```

I have read nearly all of the similar questions but I still can not find out what my problem here is.

**Edit:**

And: `sudo update-alternatives --config java`
Gives:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1058      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-armhf/jre/bin/java   1057      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1058      manual mode
```

**Edit3:**
The content of my .jar: the main is in KugelrundClient:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
kugelrundclient/
kugelrundclient/Checkbilliard_werbung.jpg
kugelrundclient/ChoosePlayer.fxml
kugelrundclient/FXMLDocument.fxml
kugelrundclient/FXMLDocumentController.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$1.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$10.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$11.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$12.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$13.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$14.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$15.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$16.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$17.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$18.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$19.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$2.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$20.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$21.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$22.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$23.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$24.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$25.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$26.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$27.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$28.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$29.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$3.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$30.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$31.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$32.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$33.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$34.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$35.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$36.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$37.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$38.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$39.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$4.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$40.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$41.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$42.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$43.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$44.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$45.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$46.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$47.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$48.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$49.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$5.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$50.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$51.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$52.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$53.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$54.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$55.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$56.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$57.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$58.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$59.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$6.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$60.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$61.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$62.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$63.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$64.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$65.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$66.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$67.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$68.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$69.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$7.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$70.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$71.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$72.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$8.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen$9.class
kugelrundclient/Fourteen.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$1.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$10.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$11.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$12.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$13.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$14.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$15.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$16.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$17.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$18.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$19.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$2.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$20.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$21.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$22.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$23.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$24.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$25.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$26.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$27.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$28.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$29.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$3.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$30.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$31.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$32.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$33.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$34.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$4.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$5.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$6.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$7.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$8.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient$9.class
kugelrundclient/KugelrundClient.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$1.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$10.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$11.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$12.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$13.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$14.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$15.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$16.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$17.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$18.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$19.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$2.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$20.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$21.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$22.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$23.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$24.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$25.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$26.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$27.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$28.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$29.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$3.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$30.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$31.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$32.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$33.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$34.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$35.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$36.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$37.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$38.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$39.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$4.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$40.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$41.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$5.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$6.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$7.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$8.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne$9.class
kugelrundclient/OneVsOne.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$1.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$10.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$11.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$12.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$2.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$3.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$4.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$5.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$6.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$7.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$8.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer$9.class
kugelrundclient/PickPlayer.class
kugelrundclient/ServerConnector.class
kugelrundclient/ShowScores$1.class
kugelrundclient/ShowScores$2.class
kugelrundclient/ShowScores$3.class
kugelrundclient/ShowScores$4.class
kugelrundclient/ShowScores.class
kugelrundclient/ShowScores.fxml
kugelrundclient/Snooker$1.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$10.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$11.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$12.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$13.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$14.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$15.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$16.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$17.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$18.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$19.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$2.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$20.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$21.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$22.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$23.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$24.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$25.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$26.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$27.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$28.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$29.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$3.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$30.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$31.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$32.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$33.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$34.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$35.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$36.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$37.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$38.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$39.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$4.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$40.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$41.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$42.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$43.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$44.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$45.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$46.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$47.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$48.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$49.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$5.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$50.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$51.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$52.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$53.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$54.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$55.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$56.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$57.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$58.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$59.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$6.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$60.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$61.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$62.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$63.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$64.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$65.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$66.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$67.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$68.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$69.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$7.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$70.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$71.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$72.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$8.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker$9.class
kugelrundclient/Snooker.class
kugelrundclient/Style_tableview.css
kugelrundclient/Style_txtInput.css
kugelrundclient/TableStatus.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$1.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$10.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$11.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$12.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$13.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$14.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$15.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$16.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$17.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$18.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$19.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$2.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$20.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$21.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$22.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$23.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$24.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$25.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$26.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$27.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$28.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$29.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$3.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$30.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$31.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$32.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$33.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$34.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$35.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$36.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$37.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$38.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$39.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$4.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$40.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$41.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$42.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$43.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$44.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$45.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$46.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$47.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$48.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$49.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$5.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$50.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$51.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$52.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$53.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$54.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$55.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$56.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$57.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$58.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$59.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$6.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$60.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$61.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$62.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$63.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$64.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$65.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$66.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$67.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$68.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$69.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$7.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$70.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$71.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$72.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$8.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo$9.class
kugelrundclient/TwoVsTwo.class
kugelrundclient/kgrnd_banner_full.png
resources/
resources/java-json.jar
```

Comment: Add the contents of your Manifest.MF file.  Also what class cannot be found?

Comment: it is auto-generated: Manifest-Version: 1.0
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build

Comment: It says packagename.Mymain.java so it knows where my main should be but can not find it

Comment: Entire stack trace. Always.

Comment: @chrylis sry if I ask but what do you mean ? the error i get in the console is just the line i posted

Comment: Try running the equivalent `java -cp myjar.jar packagename.Mymain`. Maybe you'll get a different error message that points to the source of the error.

Comment: The the jar file does not contain the main class. Check the contents with `jar tf myjar.jar`.

Comment: @Joni the main class seams to be there! Your command gives me a lot of different .class files with $+numbers at there end but one .class file with the right name is deffenetly there! I will update my output